# Sorting outcomes from ruby for loop

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to pull some information from my local active record database.  (these are doctors).
Initially in my view I had an each loop like so

```
<% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
```

This was nice, and it pulled the list of all of the doctors that I need. However now I need to have these guys pulled, but also in alphabetical order, based on their name.

So my approach with this was so,

```
<% for last_name in @doctors.last_name.all(:order => "last_name") %>
```

and then i end up calling it later in the code like so

```
<%= doctor.last_name %>
```

However I keep getting an error.  The error I get is..

```
undefined method `last_name' for #
```

In my rails console, I am able to find a doctors last name by going,

```
doctor.last.last_name
```

So, i'm not sure why the method is undefined when I am able to still easily find it in the database. Would anybody have any idea what i am missing with this?

Comment: `@doctors = Doctor.where(...).order(:last_name)`, then the usual `@doctors.each do |doctor|`

Comment: What is the `last_name` relationship here? Another model? You probably mean `<%= last_name %>`.

Comment: Please read the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide. It covers fundamentals like this.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your great help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @doctors collection will not have a last_name attribute, you need to do something like :

```
@doctors = Doctor.all.order(:last_name)
```

then

```
<% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
    <%= doctor.last_name %>
<% end %>
```